# Append Javascript in IE8 from Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I receive a JSON from a webservice that contains a variable with a script to manipulate the DOM after the page is loaded to hide some icons.(I call the webservice, receive the JSON and create all DOM with jQuery)

part of the JSON looks like this:

```
"CustomScripts":"<script type='text/javascript'>
    //manipulate DOM HERE, hide icons etc
</script>"
```

What i do is the following:

```
var text = root.CustomScripts; // root.CustomScripts contains the value
                                   of CustomScripts from the JSON i receive
var decoded = $('<div/>').html(text).text(); //Here i decode characters like &gt etc
$(decoded).appendTo('body');
```

The above works great for modern browsers but IE8 doesn't append the script.

I tried to find a solution in other posts but unfortunately i didn't find any solution.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Same behaviour if appended to the HEAD section? Maybe no other choice than using `eval()`

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: jQuery version 1.10.2